# Mac app to prompt user for Full Disk Access

Tags: macos

How can a Mac app (e.g. written in Shell or Python) [verify](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/107546) whether it has [Full Disk Access](https://macpaw.com/how-to/full-disk-access-mojave) and, if it does not, prompt the user to add the app to Full Disk Access with a single button click (similar to the image below)?

For example, a URL formatted as [x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy](http://x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy) can open the Privacy settings on a Mac. Can something similar be created using Python?

I want this to be as user-friendly as possible, so I prefer not requiring the user to search for the 'Full Disk Access' window, then search through a list for the app, then have to select the app and add it to the allowed-list etc. etc.

[image: Prompt]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Python code will open Disk Access Preferences window. You can add a window to your program with something like: *Please give me disk access. I promise to not delete your files. -App*

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy')
```

You can open the Full Disk Access page directly like this:

```
webbrowser.open('x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_AllFiles')
```

See [Open System Preferences/Privacy/Full Disk Access with url](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361045/open-system-preferences-privacy-full-disk-access-with-url) for the full list of targets.

Comment: Wow, that actually worked. Even bypassing the browser. It's not the perfect solution I was hoping for (it still requires multiple steps for the user), but I'll take it.

Comment: Yeah, sadly even if you're writing in native Swift or Obj-C you don't get a way to check or gracefully prompt the user for Full Disk Access. Apple *really* seems to want you to not use it.

Comment: BTW, I just tried this in terminal, and it seems this works without python too: `open 'x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy'`

Comment: Can we directly focus on the item under "Full Disk Access"?